# django login get AuthenticationForm doesnt contain get

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a simple login form , but I am always getting `'AuthenticationForm' object has no attribute 'get'`. I am new using django framework , but I am not sure how can it be fix thing issue ... any tips without changing too much logic ?

```
view.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.http import HttpResponse

class loginPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    def post(self, request):
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(
                request,
                username=form.get('email'),
                password=form.get('password')
            )

            if user is not None:
                return HttpResponse("Testing")
            else:
                print(user)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("loginPage") ## always goes here
```

login html

````
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
<input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
</form>```
````

Comment: Instead of using get try using `form.cleaned_data['key']`

Comment: @error404 I also tried to change to `username=form.cleandata['email'],` or ` `username=form.cleandata['email'],` , but nothing seems to work

Comment: `cleandata` is not the same as `cleaned_data`, which is what the commenter has correctly suggested you use.

Comment: my input looks like this `username=form.cleaned_data['email']`, and    `password=form.cleaned_data['password'],` , but it still the same error

Comment: you also try this ```form.instance.email``` or try this ```form.data['email']```

Comment: @AmitPatel the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because `form` object is not a dictionary instance, instead try using `form.cleaned_data.get('email')`.

Also I believe it would be much lesser code if you use django's provided generic `LoginView` instead of `TemplateView`. Here is an example of the same.

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name="users/login.html"), name='login'),
```

You can customize every aspect of this, in above example I have just used the custom template instead of using django's default template, in similar way you can also use your own form by setting `authentication_form` to appropriate form class.

For more information please check the official documentation for [LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView)

Answer (score 0):

```
if form.is_valid():
    username=form.cleaned_data['email']
    password=form.cleaned_data['password']
    user = authenticate(
                request,
                username=username,
                password=password            
    )
```

try this if this work

Comment: to be honest, the same as above , but it looks like I am requesting post , but sending get , but `form` is post , and the same python login

Comment: @AmitPatel, its would be great if you could add some explanation with this answer :)